# Using of typedef struct

Tags: c, struct, include, typedef

I want to know if there is any difference in performance, declaration, etc.

I have a file that called features.h, 
and it has a struct definition:

```
typedef struct feat_record
{
 ...
 ...
} Feature;
```

i want to use it in another file in a method, in the other file .h file I include features.h.
And my question is, if there is a difference between declaring the method in the other file .h like this:

```
void myMethod(Feature *f);
```

or like this:

```
void myMethod (struct feat_record *f);
```

Thanks

Comment: Note that you don't need two different names.  `typedef feat_record { ... } feat_record;` is fine.

Comment: @hit: You say that as if syntax somehow doesn't matter.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Did you forget a `struct`? That doesn't look valid.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth You don't need the repetition ... `typedef struct { ... } feat_record;` is fine. If `feat_record` contains a pointer to itself, use `typedef feat_record feat_record; struct feat_record { ... };`

Comment: Oops, make that `typedef struct feat_record feat_record;`

Comment: @lightnessRacesinOrbit the op asked if there is any difference, in _performance_, no.

Comment: @hit The question was "performance, declaration, etc." ... so "no" is the wrong answer to that broader question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only coding style and there is no other difference than subjective, personal preference.

The typedef version is often encouraged for programs that are in the borderland between C and C++, since it makes the style consistent with C++ types (in C++ the struct keyword is superfluous when declaring objects of a struct).

The struct tag version is mainly encouraged by the Linux camp and enforced by the Linux kernel code style guide (which does not provide much of a rationale beyond subjective opinions).

There is no obvious right or wrong, just pick the style you like and stick to it consistently.

Comment: "there is no other difference than subjective" - This is not completely true. From the language point of view, there is indeed no difference. But there are *objective* differences that are the reasons behind certain coding styles: (1) If you use the `struct` form, you can't easily change the type to a primitive one. (2) Using the typedef form hides the fact that it is probably costly to copy it. (3) You've noted yourself the consistency with C++. I assume there are more considerations.

Comment: @Elazar 1) I really don't see how the typedef would make that easier. Types are related with what limited type safety there is in the C language. 2) With that argument, you should also write out enums explicitly, to show that they aren't costly. But it is really a non-issue... a programmer who copies unknown data and then gets performance problems because of it, only have themselves to blame. Most beginner programmers know that they should always pass unknown types by reference to functions, as one example.

Comment: @Elazar 3) is not necessarily a good thing. Suppose we have a struct containing pointers, written for C but compiled in C++ turning the struct into a "public class". It might then be better to show that the code was written and intended for C, to show that no thought was made about the constructor or copy ctr/assignment operator/destructor for the struct/class. So all-in-all, I think these arguments are all fairly subjective and only valid on case-to-case basis.

Comment: for (1) say what used to be a struct is now an int. Now you have to change *everywhere* in your code from `struct bla` to `int`. You made the struct-ness part of the type's interface, effectively (just like using any bare primitive; that's what `typedef` is for). If what you say is "the objective reasons are not clear-cut or highly important at all, so the decision is basically a matter of taste" I'd agree.

Comment: saying about something that "it is not necessarily a good thing" means it has some (possibly negative) value.

Comment: @Elazar Aha, you are talking about code maintenance, I misunderstood you then. Indeed code containing the struct keyword explicitly will not be as generic, from a code maintenance point-of-view.

Answer (score -2):

The difference is that the `typedef` declaration of `Feature` (which may or may not include the definition of `feat_record`) must precede the function declaration using it, whereas

```
void myMethod (struct feat_record *f);
```

stands on its own as an interface declaration; it does not depend on a preceding `typedef` or other declaration.

Nevertheless, it is better to declare `struct feat_record;` first, if only to silence an inevitable compiler warning. And such a declaration is required before the function declaration in the file that *implements* `myMethod`.

Ultimately, the difference is style, namely verboseness: you should decide whether you want to refer to all structs as `struct` in your program. It means more typing, but serves as a reminder to initialize things. (Or, if you prefer, a metadata tag for things that must be handled as a `struct`.)

As for the compiled program, there is no conceivable difference.

Comment: It does require a preceding struct declaration however (complete or incomplete), so it is not really standing on its own any more than the typedef. This is all just subjective coding style.

Comment: @Lundin No, it's an elaborated-type-specifier (in C++ parlance, not sure of the C terminology) and no preceding declaration is needed whatsoever.

Comment: If you have no definition of the type anywhere, you can't access the contents pointed at. You will also get plenty of compiler warnings. It only makes sense to write code like this if you are implementing an "opaque type", but if you do, you will want a global (file scope) declaration of the type anyhow. So what exactly is the advantage here?

Comment: @Lundin Ah, it's called a "tag." See C11 §6.7.2.1/8. What are you on about? You said it requires a preceding declaration and it doesn't. That's wrong. It has the effect of a forward declaration of the `struct`.

Comment: Alright, it does not require a forward declaration, but it is still an incomplete type, only valid locally in that function. Who, in the real world, gets happier by that? As already mentioned, I can think of no case where it would be useful.

Comment: @Lundin It's the same as a forward declaration. It's not tied in any particular way to the function. Not sure what you're thinking about, but this isn't the proper forum to explain forward declarations to you.

Comment: And this is this the proper forum to teach you about incomplete/opaque type or the difference between definition and declaration. Let me spell it out clearly... how exactly do you intend to use `f` inside the function? You can't access its contents, you can't do anything meaningful with it whatsoever, unless there is a definition present. And how is the `myMethod` function meaningful to the program, without a definition of the type available?

Comment: -1 A struct declaration inside a prototype is local to the prototype is there's no other declaration of the struct in scope, so this declaration of myMethod is incompatible with the definition of myMethod, which necessarily follows a definition of struct feat_record if it is used in myMethod. As gcc says, " warning: ‘struct feat_record’ declared inside parameter list ... warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want"

Comment: "It has the effect of a forward declaration of the struct. " -- No, it certainly doesn't ... not inside a prototype ... the scope of the declaration is limited to the prototype. Is this the proper forum to teach you about things?

Comment: @Lundin "it is still an incomplete type, only valid locally in that function" -- Actually it's only valid locally to the *prototype*.

Comment: @Lundin Forward declarations are useful in a header file. There's no "inside the function."

Comment: @JimBalter Interesting, that is a difference between C and C++ that I didn't know. However, my answer is still correct… even more so because I *didn't* mention declaration of the `struct` as a side effect.

Comment: Your answer is not correct. "it does not require any preceding typedef" is only true in a narrow sense that isn't relevant to the question ... such a prototype is useless because it isn't compatible with any function definition of `myMethod`.

Comment: @JimBalter Ah, now I understand. The scope of the identifier is also the scope of the underlying entity. I had assumed that as there is one namespace for struct tags, two struct tags with the same name refer to the same struct. In C++, even if the scope of a struct name is limited to a declaration, it refers to that uniquely-named struct, because the C++ ODR applies to structs. Anyway, the correct usage simply requires the implementation source file to include a `struct` definition before the declaration, whereas the interface file works as I suggest… So 6.7.2.1/8 is poorly designed at best.